# What is wrong with 100000 factorial using ContinuationMonad?

Tags: f#, monads, tail-recursion, continuations

It is powerful technique using recursion because its strong describable feature. Tail recursion provides more powerful computation than normal recursion because it changes recursion into iteration. Continuation-Passing Style (CPS) can change lots of loop codes into tail recursion. Continuation Monad provides recursion syntax but in essence it is tail recursion, which is iteration. It is supposed to reasonable use Continuation Monad for 100000 factorial. Here is the code.

```
type ContinuationBuilder() =
   member b.Bind(x, f) = fun k -> x (fun x -> f x k)
   member b.Return x = fun k -> k x
   member b.ReturnFrom x = x
(*
type ContinuationBuilder =
  class
    new : unit -> ContinuationBuilder
    member Bind : x:(('d -> 'e) -> 'f) * f:('d -> 'g -> 'e) -> ('g -> 'f)
    member Return : x:'b -> (('b -> 'c) -> 'c)
    member ReturnFrom : x:'a -> 'a
  end
*)
let cont = ContinuationBuilder()
//val cont : ContinuationBuilder
let fac n =
    let rec loop n =
      cont {
              match n with
              | n when n = 0I -> return 1I   
              | _ -> let! x = fun f -> f n
                     let! y = loop (n - 1I)   
                     return x * y
           }
    loop n (fun x -> x)

let x2 = fac 100000I
```

There is wrong message: "Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException."

What is wrong with 100000 factorial using ContinuationMonad?

Comment: "Tail recursion provides more powerful computation than normal recursion because it changes recursion into iteration."

This isn't strictly true.  If the recursion is too complex to be turned into a loop, then it simply re-uses the current stack frame for the next call of the function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to compile the project in Release mode or check the "Generate tail calls" option in project properties (or use `--tailcalls+` if you're running the compiler via command line).

By default, tail call optimization is not enabled in Debug mode. The reason is that, if tail-calls are enabled, you will not see as useful information about stack traces. So, disabling them by default gives you more pleasant debugging experience (even in Debug mode, the compiler optimizes tail-recursive functions that call themselves, which handles most situations).

Comment: It didn't work when i followed your suggestions. My platform is win7 + VS2010 + .net4.0.

Comment: Sorry. It works. The version should be release version otherwise debug version.

Comment: The Delay is needed anyway. Try yet more than 100000, you will see the stack overflow even in realese mode.

Comment: THANK YOU! I've spent a full day trying to figure out why I always got a stack overflow on the continuation examples around on SO

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to add this memeber to your monad builder:

```
member this.Delay(mk) = fun c -> mk () c
```